# count of subsets with sum divisible by $3$

Tags: number-theory, combinations, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem, binomial-distribution

How do I find the count of sub-arrays whose sum of elements is divisible by $3$? The elements are to be chosen from $0,1,2$. These elements can appear any number of time in array. The number of appearance of the elements is also given.

For example: $$[0,1,2]$$
Number of 0's = 1
Number of 1's = 1
Number of 2's = 1

Answer is $4$: as valid sub-arrays are $$[], [0], [1,2], [0,1,2] $$

Note:
Instead of generating all the possible sub-arrays, looking for a way to compute the subset count by using the appearance count of elements, e.g., occurrence of 0's, 1's, and 2's

Looked into following but couldn't use it for the problem:
[How do I count the subsets of a set whose number of elements is divisible by 3? 4?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/918/how-do-i-count-the-subsets-of-a-set-whose-number-of-elements-is-divisible-by-3)

Answer (score 0):

I take the liberty of tackling this question from a different (and to my opinion, more useful) viewpoint.

let $\epsilon_i$ be independent identically distributed random variables that distribute $\epsilon_i\sim\text{Uniform}(\{0,1,2\})$. Now define $$S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n\epsilon_i \mod{3}$$
By induction, it is quite easy to see that $S_n\sim\text{Uniform}(\{0,1,2\})$ (can you prove it?).
Hence $\mathbb{P}(S_n=0)=\mathbb{P}(3\text{ diviedes }\sum_{i=1}^n\epsilon_i)=1/3$. Now to go back from probability to counting, we multiply by the cardinality of the whole probability space; $3^N$ in our case.
Thus the answer is $3^N\cdot 1/3=3^{N-1}$.

Comment: I've updated the question for more clarity, would you please have a look and update the answer, if possible, thanks.

Comment: So you asked a trivial counting question?

Comment: Instead of generating all the possible sub-arrays, looking for a way to compute the subset count by using the appearance count of elements, e.g., occurrence of 0's, 1's, and 2's.
Something like this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1721926/number-of-subsets-of-a-set-with-even-sum-using-combinatorics-or-binomial#:~:text=If%20o%3D0%2C%20all%202,%3D2N%E2%88%921%20subsets. However, instead of even sum, here, interested in the sum divisible by 3.

Comment: any insights, pls?

Comment: @AlonYariv

(1) Finding an exact solution to this variant --- or even the original --- subset sum problem is non-trivial for large sets of boxes.

(2) It is known that the probability mentioned above is 1/3 **only** in the limit of an infinitely large set of boxes.

(3) The discrepancy between your analysis and the empirical probabilities lies in how your uniformly distributed epsilon_i variables correspond only approximately to anything in the real problem. For any N, the count of numbers <= N, grouped by mod 3, are not equal to each other.

Answer (score 0):

**PARTIAL SOLUTION**

Happy to hear better solutions.

My answer is: approximately 1/3 the total count of coins in the boxes. The approximation is better the more coins exist.

(1) If all the boxes have **exactly** one coin, then there surely exists an [exact answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/329645/how-to-compute-the-sum-of-every-k-th-binomial-coefficient?rq=1).

(2) If all the boxes have **at most** one coin, then there likely exists an exact answer: count only the boxes with exactly one coin, then proceed as in Case 1 above. Here is my logic:

- Let $E$ be the number of empty boxes.
- Copy each of the original subsets from Case 1.
- To each copied subset, append a set containing any number $e = E$ of empty boxes and no non-empty boxes.
- Each copied subset has the same total count of coins as its original subset.
- Therefore, the probability that a copied subset will have a coin count divisible by 3 is equal to the analogous probability for its original subset.
- Therefore, the union of the *family* of original subsets with the family of copied subsets has the same probability as the family of original subsets.
- The above logic holds true for any subset with $e$ empty boxes (there is exactly one such subset when $e = E$).
- Decrement $e$ by 1: $e = e - 1$.
- The above logic still holds (even when $e > 1$ and there is more than one empty subset with $e$ empty boxes).
- Loop through the argument above until $e = 0$. The above logic still holds.
- At any point above, the probability can be converted into a count by multiplying the probability by the number of subsets.

(3) If there is even one box containing two coins, then I do not have an exact answer. But inputing a suitable set of boxes (*i.e.*, total number of boxes <= 200) into any dynamic programming solution to the subset sum problem (see online) will show that the empirical probability approaches 1/3 as well. And as in Case 2, the probability can be converted into a count very easily.